# Determining logic equivalence using laws of logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$ (p  \longrightarrow q) \wedge(p \longrightarrow r) \equiv p  \longrightarrow(q \wedge r) $$
Using the left side:
$$  (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \text{(Eliminating the conditional)}$$
$$ \equiv ((\neg p \vee q) \wedge \neg p) \vee ((\neg p \vee q) \wedge r) \text{(Distribution)}$$ 
$$ \equiv \neg p \vee ((\neg p \vee q) \wedge r)  \text{(Absorption)}$$

From here I have distributed and gone in circles multiple times. This is the closest I have gotten to the solution.

I have tried using the right hand side as well, starting with:

$$ \neg p \vee (q \wedge r)$$

and managed to get the answer, but I can't seem to do it with the left hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
(p  \longrightarrow q) \wedge(p \longrightarrow r) &\equiv  (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \tag{removing conditional}\\ 
&\equiv \neg p \vee (q \wedge r) \tag{distributive law} \\ 
&\equiv p  \longrightarrow(q \wedge r) \tag{converting to conditional}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Oh, it didn't occur to me do that, thank you!